# Is there any function to sort an array keys based in the consecutive number/ itself in php?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm tried many sorting functions in order to have an specific key order in a php array, this is my current array:

```
Array(
    [1] => 1.txt
    [21] => 2-1.txt
    [221] => 2-2-1.txt
    [22] => 2-2.txt
    [231] => 2-3-1.txt
    [2321] => 2-3-2-1.txt
    [232] => 2-3-2.txt
    [23] => 2-3.txt
    [2] => 2.txt
)
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
Array(
    [1] => 1.txt
    [2] => 2.txt
    [21] => 2-1.txt
    [22] => 2-2.txt
    [221] => 2-2-1.txt
    [23] => 2-3.txt
    [231] => 2-3-1.txt
    [232] => 2-3-2.txt
    [2321] => 2-3-2-1.txt
)
```

Does somebody can give me a hand?

Comment: Have you tried `uksort()`?

Comment: @Rizier123 I think you meant to say `natsort()`?

Comment: @mistermartin Almost but not quite. `natsort()` sorts the array based on values and not keys. OP wants to do a natural sort comparison, but on the keys. So he needs to use `uksort()` with `strnatcmp` as callback.

Comment: @Rizier123 you're right, i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `uksort` with `strcmp` on keys:

```
uksort( $array, 'strcmp' );
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1.txt
    [2] => 2.txt
    [21] => 2-1.txt
    [22] => 2-2.txt
    [221] => 2-2-1.txt
    [23] => 2-3.txt
    [231] => 2-3-1.txt
    [232] => 2-3-2.txt
    [2321] => 2-3-2-1.txt
)
```

Comment: Thank you for accepting answer. ... But take a look at @AbraCadaver answer: better nickname, better answer. :)

Comment: Ha thanks!  I don't think it matter to them.  If you had posted 100 lines of code and it worked for them that's all they care about.

Answer (score 2):

`ksort()` sorts the array by key and use the `SORT_NATURAL` to sort naturally which is the order that you have shown:

```
ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL);
```